# Extract value from string and get its content

Tags: string, lua

I'm using LUA to extract a value from a long string.

String (shorted) looks like:

```
local input = "...&lt;/anno:rotation&lt;anno:contentY&gt;40.900000000000006&lt;/anno:contentY&lt;..."
```

I'm looking for the quickest / easiest way to extract the value between `&lt;anno:contentY&gt;` and `&lt;/anno:contentY&lt;`. In this example '40.900000000000006'.

Is there any better way then using `string.find` to get start and end position and then using `string.split`?

Comment: `local rot = tonumber(input:match("&lt;anno:contentY&gt;(.-)&lt;/anno:contentY&lt;"))`

Comment: A better solution would be to decode the html entity, and use XML parser if you are going to need more values from the string.